# Dynamically created text box's ontextchanged event not firing when assigned an ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I read all related posts , but still could not understand the prob that am currently facing.On  Oninit I create table with text boxes as follows, when i assign an id to the text box the textchanged event does not fire, but when i do not assign an ID it fires. Cant reason out why. Kindly help.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

    PopulateTextBoxes();
    base.OnInit(e);
    }
protected void PopulateTextBoxes()
{
    int quantityRequired = 0;
    quantityRequired =GetQuantity();
    for (int j = 0; j < quantityRequired; j++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        //tb.ID = j.ToString() +":RowTbx";---> this when uncommented does not fire my      tb_textChanged event while left commented the textchanged event is fired. Cant understand why? How is assigning an ID affect event Firing, I need to have the ID to further update my Db.                    
        tb.AutoPostBack = true;
        tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
        cell1.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        CheckBox chBox = new CheckBox();
        chBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chBox_CheckedChanged);
        chBox.AutoPostBack = true;
        cell2.Controls.Add(chBox);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.Height = Unit.Pixel(25);
        img.ImageUrl = "HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath" + "/Images/" +"img.jpeg";
        cell3.Controls.Add(img);
        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
        tbl_Serial.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to mark the right answer. It could help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id you are setting is not a valid control id.

Refer: [Control.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx)

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore
>   character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces
>   or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

try this:

```
tb.ID = "RowTbx" + j;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. You saved me a lot of time :) Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

dont use `:` for `ID`. try this instead

```
tb.ID = j.ToString() + "_RowTbx";
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. You saved me a lot of time :) Thanks a ton!